# readregistry issue

Tags: registry, nant

I'm sure that there's something silly that I'm missing here..

I'm trying to query the registry (Windows 7 64bit) to get my Python install path. For some reason, I'm getting:

**Registry Path Not Found! - key=3D'SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\2.7\InstallPath\';hive=3D'LocalMachine'**

However, if I replace my key with the sample in the documentation, all works fine. I've rebooted since installing Python (not sure whether or not that makes a difference). What am I missing here?

The task I'm using is:

```
<readregistry verbose="true" key="SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\2.7\InstallPath\" property="installDir" />
```

Comment: Does it really exists? You can check it from `cmd` with `reg query HLKM\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\2.7\InstallPath\ /v installDir`. E.g. I don't have such key. I have XP 32 bit, though.

Comment: Yessir.. `reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\2.7\InstallPath\ /ve` yields the correct path.

Comment: Are you sure, hive key should be named as `LocalMachine` and not as `HKLM`, `LOCAL_MACHINE` or `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`?

Comment: Yes. That's as per nant docs.

Comment: Could this be an issue with registry key redirection: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384253%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#redirected__shared__and_reflected_keys_under_wow64

Answer (score 1):

The 'readregistry' task 'key' attribute is misleading.
It does not represent the registry key but instead the key *and* value name.
So to get the value of 'installDir' from the 'HLKM\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\2.7\InstallPath' key,
and then set it in a property named 'somePropName', what you have to do is :

```
<readregistry property="somePropName" key="SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\2.7\InstallPath\installDir" hive="LocalMachine" />
```